# Facebook Permanent Access Token

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-access-token

I am working as part of a team for a company that wishes to display the time of the last post on a dashboard for a Facebook post. This is for a webpage.

To do this, an access token is required.

The standard Facebook token lasts for 1-2 hours, before it becomes unusable. There is an option to exchange this temporary token for a longer-term version , which lasts 60 days (~2 months). Is there a token that is permanent? (ie. Has no expiry date).

**EDIT**

This is for a HTML page that has some PHP code to display the time of the last post for a specific Facebook profile.

**EDIT2**

This is the situation:

The company I am working for currently has a HTML page that has a lot of statistics such as weather, alerts, graphs and other JavaScript widgets on a page. I have been asked to display a little section that displays the time of the last post for a certain Facebook profile. To do this, should I build a 'Facebook App', or is there another better way to retrieve this information? Can I use the Facebook API to get the last post without creating a Facebook app?

Comment: Yes, get a page access token (I’m assuming you are talking about posts on a page by the page itself?) _using_ a long-lived user access token. This page access token will have no default expiry.

Comment: I am talking about getting the time of the last post for a specific Facebook profile. Can a page access token be used for this? If not, is there another suitable token?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `offline_access` has been deprecated so there is no option to get permanent `access_token`. The longest one you can get lasts for 60 days.

If you want to show date of the last post for specific account (I suppose this is for viewers account) you can create Facebook app, ask for read_stream extended permission, check date of the last post and display it in one request (use JavaScript SDK).

You can fetch it last post with

```
/me/feed?limit=1
```

Comment: If I create a Facebook app to do the above steps, do I need to get a new access_token every 60 days?

Comment: The simpliest way is to get short lived token which lasts for 1 hour (or 2) each time user is entering your page. When he authorizes your app he won't be asked again each time he visits.

Comment: Can you please look at my Edit2 in the first post. Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid that you have to create Facebook app and "Log in" into your page using it (to grant permissions for your app). I thought that you may need see user's last post, then you don't need any of extended permissions, just the simpliest one - you can fetch user's last post with `/me/posts?limit=1`. Without app you cannot get permissions to see user's posts.